# Serializer for Drawing.Color using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to change the default serializer in `Newtonsoft.Json` for `System.Drawing.Color`. Instead of the default string value I would like to fire this method:

```
public string ToHtml(Color c)
    => $"rgba({c.R},{c.G},{c.B},{c.A / 255f})";
```

Every time an object of type `Color` is to be resolved. This is the format to be consumed by CSS.

What is an elegant, yet simple way to accomplish this?

#### EDIT

Here is an example json I want to create:

```
{
  "color": "rgba(80,80,80,0.5)"
}
```

Comment: Google a bit please... http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/

Comment: You would make a `JsonConverter` like the `ColorConverter` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421904/how-to-use-a-jsonconverter-with-jtoken-toobject-method

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON you want to create?  It's not clear from your question if you're trying to embed a string in your json, or a [JConstructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351479/why-is-jconstructor).

Comment: @dbc example json added :)

Comment: got it working, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working. Please consider [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that others can profit from your learning experience.